# Django nullbooleanfield is defaulting to 'False' when left empty on form, shouldn't be Null?

Tags: django

models.py

```
my_field = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
```

forms.py

```
my_field = forms.BooleanField(
    label='my_field',
    required=False,
    widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=[(True,'yes'),(False,'no')]))
```

When the form is submitted without the radio buttons selected, the form saves and defaults to false. Shouldn't it default to Null?

Comment: Shouldn't you use a `NullBooleanField` here in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form uses a `forms.BooleanField` as form field, so it has no notion of `None`. You should use a [**`NullBooleanField`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#nullbooleanfield):

```
class SomeForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.NullBooleanField(
        label='my_field',
        required=False,
        widget=forms.RadioSelect(choices=[(True,'yes'),(False,'no')])
    )
```

As the [documentation of the `NullBooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#nullbooleanfield) says:

> **`NullBooleanField`**
>
> **`class NullBooleanField(**kwargs)`**
>
> - Default widget: NullBooleanSelect
> - **Empty value: `None`**
> - Normalizes to: A Python `True`, `False` or `None` value.
> - Validates nothing (i.e., it never raises a ValidationError).

Whereas for a [`BooleanField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#booleanfield), the empty value is `False`:

> **`BooleanField`**
>
> **`class BooleanField(**kwargs)`**
>
> - Default widget: CheckboxInput
> - **Empty value: `False`**
> - Normalizes to: A Python `True` or `False` value.
> - Validates that the value is `True` (e.g. the check box is checked) if the field has `required=True`.
> - Error message keys: required